# Change date format of yyyy-dd-mm

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to change date format of yyyy-dd-mm in SQL Server?

I have tried to change the format using formatting string but format didn't change

Comment: Change the format of what exactly? Dates don't have a "format", that's a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: As in an SSMS display setting?

Comment: 1) Where are you viewing the format? SSMS? Your app? 2) What format do you want? 3) Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score -2):

The date format can be changed using Date and Time Conversions in sql server.
The required format could be achieved by using CONVERT(varchar, date_column,31) in your script.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Please refer above link for another format.

Comment: Are you implying dates are persisted in varchar columns?